# vuejs: can we give props to async component via dynamic component pattern <component :is="type" opts="asyncCompOptions">?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am struggling with following vuejs application scenario dynamic components + async component pattern.
Everything works fine, but remains only one problem: 
How can I access props data passed in via the

```
<component :is="asyncComp" opts="someDataForAsyncComp">
```

please see live fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/matiascx/wjab87om/8/

Here is the code:

```
    <div id="app">
by dynamic Component:
  <component
    v-for="item in items"
    :is="item.component"
    :opts="item.options">    <!-- can we give props data to async component here? --> 
  </component><div>
```

Following is the js section:

```
    Vue.component('node3', function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve({
      template: '<div>I am async node3!</div>',
      created: function(){
         console.log(this.opts);  // can we access props transferred into async component via component
      }
    })
  }, 1000)
})
Vue.component('node', {
  template: '<div>must be static tpl!</div>',
  props: ['opts'],
  computed: {
    log: function() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.opts);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  created: function(){
  console.log(this.opts);
  }
});

Vue.component('node2', {
  template: '<div>node2</div>',
  props: ['opts'],
  computed: {
    log: function() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.opts);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  created: function(){
    console.log("dfdsfsdfa");
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      newItem: {
        component: "",
        options: ""
      },
      items: [{
        component: "node",
        options: {
           type: "node",
           tpl: "<div>node: {{ opts }} {{ log }}</div>"
        }
      }, 
      {
        component: "node2",
        options: {
            type: "node2",
          tpl: "<div>node2: {{ opts }} {{ log }}</div>"
        }
      },
       {
        component: "node3",
        options: {
            type: "node3",
          tpl: "<div>node3: {{ opts }} {{ log }}</div>"
       }
      }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isButtonDisplayed() {
      return this.newItem.component && this.newItem.options
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push(this.newItem);
      this.newItem = {
        component: "",
        options: ""
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added three lines to your jsfiddle:

```
// dynamic component
var _this = this
this.$nextTick(()=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(_this.$options._parentVnode.data.attrs.opts))})
// static component
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.$options.propsData.opts))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/wjab87om/11/

I don't think this is the best way to do it though, it would be better to ask Evan.

Comment: thanks for your warmly feedback~!  The line you add works well for the component 'node'(It is a normal component), but it does not work for the component 'node3' which is a async component. Can you have a check?